# Are Properties in Objective-C "Static"?

Tags: objective-c, oop, properties, static, scope

I'm building up an understanding of scope in object oriented programming, specifically Objective-C. I understand that static variables are variables that will not loose their value throughout use within multiple methods in the class in which they are defined*. **Do properties behave in the same way?** I know that properties go back to their initial value for each instance of the class within it's subclasses. But, **they do retain value (pre-set or modified via various methods) throughout the entire class, correct?**

*Do static variables only retain their value throughout use within multiple methods in a the class in which they are defined, or do they retain their values throughout all instances of the class in which they are defined in throughout various subclasses? If so, then I could see why properties would not be considered as having a static behavior. But if not, then properties could be considered static, correct?

Also, are static variables any different than global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance properties in Objective-C are backed by instance variables by default, so they do not behave like static variables. You can set a property on an instance, and the value would remain the same until you set it to something different.

However, properties are simply a special syntax on top of method calls. There is no limit to what you can do inside a method, so theoretically you could "back" an instance property by a static variable, and the compiler will take it just fine. However, an arrangement like that would not be readable, so I would highly recommend against using it.